# Postgres - copy table INCLUDING CONSTRAINT doesn't include constraint

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, constraint, table

How come that statement don't copy constraints if I explicitly ask for it?

```
CREATE TABLE backup_schema.permissions (LIKE public.permissions INCLUDING DEFAULTS INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS INCLUDING INDEXES INCLUDING STORAGE INCLUDING COMMENTS);
INSERT INTO backup_schema.permissions
    SELECT *
    FROM public.permissions
    WHERE community_id=123;
```

verifying with pgadmin3 I discovered that constraints on the new table(eg.:backup_schema) was: 
[image]

but in the original table in public schema was like this:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) says about `INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS` (emphasis mine):

> Not-null constraints are always copied to the new table. `CHECK` constraints will only be copied if `INCLUDING CONSTRAINTS` is specified; **other types of constraints will never be copied**. Also, no distinction is made between column constraints and table constraints — when constraints are requested, all check constraints are copied.

Foreign keys obviously fall into this 'other constraints' group, this is why the two FKs of yours are not copied over.

Interestingly, the documentation for version 9.3 has a different wording, not stating the above so clearly.

Comment: 9.4 and devel still have the same wording. Will you submit a patch to the documentation? If not, I will do it.

Comment: @Colin'tHart could you?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: again thankyou for your reply, it gave me a nice push to fix my problem